# What is this machine in Wall Market?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

While in what appears to be public toilets in Wall Market, I noticed this vending machine:

[image: strange vending machine in wall market]

When approaching it, there's no action available, and can't see any writing on it.

What is this machine? Does it have any purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the vending machine more, I remember the purpose of this vending machine.

While there are no actions available to interact with it, you can interact with it during the [The Party That Never Stops](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/The_Party_Never_Stops) side quest.

The items you will obtain will vary based on how many enemies you have scanned with the Assess Materia. Inevitably you will receive a specific item for the quest, "The Sauce", which continues the side quest and thus making the vending machine no longer interactable.